# Click on all hidden sublinks in a menu using a loop

Tags: java, loops, selenium-webdriver

I am using WebDriver 2 with Java.
I am testing a menu that has hidden sublinks that are visible once a user hovers over them.  I need to hover over the menu, click on each link within the menu, go the appropriate page, return back to the original page and repeat all the steps for the next link. I can do this using the following method which does that for each sublink separately. My goal is to create a method that will do all those steps using a loop, that can be re-used for similar menus. Here is the method that I have right now without a loop (I have created custom methods hoverOver and waitForElementVisibility).

hoverOver is:

```
public void hoverOver(WebElement element){
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
}
```

waitForElementVisibility is:

```
public void waitForElementVisibility(WebElement element){
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
}
```

And the method for menu and sublinks is(this is the method that I want to create as a loop):

```
public void checkLinksInTopMenu(WebElement menu, WebElement sublink1, 
WebElement sublink2, WebElement sublink3){
hoverOver(menu);
waitForElementVisibility(sublink1);
sublink1.click();
driver.navigate().back();
hoverOver(menu);
waitForElementVisibility(sublink2);
sublink2.click();
driver.navigate().back();
hoverOver(menu);
waitForElementVisibility(sublink3);
sublink3.click();
driver.navigate().back();
}
```

Please help me out, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if any exceptions, what is the exception?

Actions class will work for mouse over.

no need of wait statement in hoverOver method.

try like the following

mouseover followed by clicking on submenu item.

builder.moverToElement(webElement).click(webElement).build().perform();

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This code allows me to click on one sublink only. My goal is to create some kind of a loop that will hover over the main menu, then click on first sublink (which takes me to another page), return back to the main menu on the original page, hover over same menu again, click on second sublink and so on for 5 sublinks located in this menu. If a loop is possible, it would be more efficient and re-usable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if any exceptions, what is the exception?

Actions class will work for mouse over.

no need of wait statement in hoverOver method.

try like the following

mouseover followed by clicking on submenu item.

builder.moverToElement(webElement).click(webElement).build().perform();

if above code works then pass two arguements (webelement1, webelement2) to the method

webelement1 to hover the main menu
webelement2 to click on the submenu item

you can do this by simply calling a method with two parameters.
please let me know if you need any help.